# Concatenating over grouped strings

Tags: pandas

I have a df of grouped strings similar to this:

```
chat_type         message
Account           My Account is missing money
Account           I need to update my account
Benefits          My benefits suck
Benefits          Where is my benefit check
```

Desired output

```
chat_type          message
Account            My Account is missing money I need to update my account
Benefits           My benefits suck Where is my benefits check
```

My attempted solution of

```
dfn = df.groupby('chat_type')['message'].join()
```

returns this message

```
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'join'
```

Comment: df.groupby('chat_type')['message'].apply(','.join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df=df.groupby('chat_type')['message'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```